# Set a build Variable based on a Trigger in Bamboo

Tags: triggers, bamboo

Im using bamboo to build a bigger C++ project (not huge)

I have a Build plan which works fine, but for "Quick Build" checks, I deactivate the archive and installer creation. (because this takes up to > 5 minutes)

Now the Question:
I want to set a Variable for the build based on how it was triggered.
So if it was triggered by a check-in/push I should run a quick build, without any "archiving". But if it is started as a Daily build, the archive/installer should be created.

Is this possible? and if yes, how?
Or is there another way to achieve a similar result?

Answer (score 1):

Check the Metadata tab on your plan build. It will contain entries which you can use as variables (by prefixing them with `$bamboo` first) in order to deduce how your build was started.

- `ScheduledTriggerReason.scheduledDate` - exists if build was triggered by a periodic trigger
- `ManualBuildTriggerReason.userName` - exists if build was triggered manually by someone
- `repository.revision.number` vs `repository.previous.revision.number` - these are part of the job build of a plan and are different when the job was triggered by repository changes (i.e. merged PR)

Inspecting one or a combination of the above will allow you to set your variable correspondingly.